# Use the X from for-loop as part of variable name (Pythnon)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, variables, spreadsheet

I have a problem that may be obvious for Pythonist, but I just can't google it out.

Shortly:

I want to use `x` from the `for x in my_data_header` as part of my variable name. For example instead of hardcoding `my_data.selected_column` use `my_data.x` to loop trough all columns.

Longer:

I want to make boxplot from scientific data imported from the spreadsheet. In one columns are the treatments designation by which I trim dataset. Other are measurements I want to draw boxplots from. I need to loop trough measurement columns and export the boxplots. So the x of the for loop have to be used in:
*selection of the column (within each treatment), titling the boxplot, nameing the export .png file,... 
I could perform steps separately, but coudn't compose the loop.
What is recommended approach for looping through spreadsheet columns with complex task where you have to refer to column titles? (I will complete information if needed.)
I am trying to switch from RStudio/Markdown/Knit to Python. 
Thank you in advance!

---

Comment: use `my_data[x]` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It was the pd.DataFrame issue: my prior used date.read method imported as non-pandas compatible. I past my working code below if someone find it useful. If SO community find it irrelevant just delete all together.

```
`import numpy as np`
`import pandas as pd
`import seaborn as sns

`data = pd.read_excel('/media/Data/my_file.xlsx', 0)`
`h=data.columns #read headers line`
`d = pd.DataFrame(data) 
`print(type(d)) #check that is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`
`for x in h:`
`    yy=d[x] #forreference to column`
`    bp = sns.boxplot(x='Column_with_treatments', y=yy, data=data)  #make graphs`
`    fig = bp.get_figure()  #put created graph in to obeject fig`
`    nn=yy.name+'_name_you_want.png' #crate file name string`
`    print(nn) # it print in log the column name of present graph`
`    fig.savefig(nn) #save graph image`
`    #plt.show() # it would show each image, but you need to close it to continue`
`    plt.clf() #clear the present graph from memory`
```